# Using numba to accelerate odeint, issues when trying to pass a dictionary and custom object

Tags: python, python-3.x, ode, numba

I am working on a personal project, to code a quadcopter simulation (and control) in Python, as a learning project. I am using the `scipy` integrator `odeint` and I am quite disappointing in the long computing time. So I wish to use `numba` to accelerate my integration. I call `odeint` every timestep, as I have to create commands after each simulated timestep.

At first, I had issues when my function to integrate (`state_dot`) was a method of the `Quadcopter` class. So I made it a separate function, but I am now having problems defining the right types when I decorate my function with `@jit`. The `state_dot` function has a dictionary (`params`) as an input argument (I've read that numba supports dictionaries), but also was a custom class (`wind`), because my wind model is a method of that class. If I exclude the `wind` for now, using `numba.typed.Dict` doesn't seem to work to import the dictionary.

To import the `wind` object in the function, I've seen the numba type `object_` being used, but Python doesn't find a `object_` in numba.

I am using numba version 0.45.0, and Python 3.7.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from numba import jit, void, float_, int_
import numba

class Quadcopter:

    def __init__(self):

        # Quad Params
        # ---------------------------
        mB  = 1.2       # mass (kg)
        params = {}
        params["mB"]   = mB
        self.params = params


        # Initial State
        # ---------------------------
        self.state = np.zeros(3)

    def update(self, t, Ts, cmd, wind):

        self.state = odeint(state_dot, self.state, [t,t+Ts], args = (cmd, self.params, wind))[1]


@jit(void(float_[:], float_, float_[:], numba.typed.Dict )) #(nopython = True)
def state_dot(state, t, cmd, params, wind):

    # Import Params
    # ---------------------------    
    mB   = params["mB"]

    # Import State Vector
    # ---------------------------  
    x      = state[0]
    y      = state[1]
    z      = state[2]

    # Motor Dynamics and Rotor forces (Second Order System: https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SecondOrderSystems)
    # ---------------------------
    print(cmd)

    # Wind Model
    # ---------------------------
    [velW, qW1, qW2] = wind.randomWind(t)
    print(velW)

    # State Derivative Vector
    # ---------------------------
    sdot     = np.zeros(3)
    sdot[0]  = x*t + 0.1
    sdot[1]  = y*t + 0.1
    sdot[2]  = z*t + 0.1


    return sdot


class Wind:

    def __init__(self):

        # Normally, average wind would be randomly set here
        self.velW_med = 5.0
        self.qW1_med  = 0.2
        self.qW2_med  = 0.1

    def randomWind(self, t):

        # Normally, wind values would be a sine function dependant of current time
        velW = self.velW_med
        qW1  = self.qW1_med
        qW2  = self.qW2_med

        return velW, qW1, qW2

# Set time
Ti = 0
Ts = 0.005
Tf = 10

# Initialize quadcopter and wind
quad = Quadcopter()
wind = Wind()

# Simulation
t = Ti
while round(t,3) < Tf:
    cmd = np.array([1,2,1,3])
    quad.update(t, Ts, cmd, wind)
    print(quad.state)
    t += Ts
```

The error received is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/JOHN-Laptop/Documents/Code Dev/Test/question_quad.py", line 29, in <module>
    @jit(void(float_[:], float_, float_[:], numba.typed.Dict )) #(nopython = True)
  File "C:\Users\JOHN-Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\decorators.py", line 186, in wrapper
    disp.compile(sig)
  File "C:\Users\JOHN-Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JOHN-Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 676, in compile
    args, return_type = sigutils.normalize_signature(sig)
  File "C:\Users\JOHN-Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\sigutils.py", line 48, in normalize_signature
    check_type(ty)
  File "C:\Users\JOHN-Laptop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numba\sigutils.py", line 43, in check_type
    "instance, got %r" % (ty,))
TypeError: invalid type in signature: expected a type instance, got <class 'numba.typed.typeddict.Dict'>
```

The full code can be viewed here : https://github.com/bobzwik/Quadcopter_SimCon/blob/dev_numba/Simulation/quadFiles/quad.py

If I am missing any information, feel free to ask.

EDIT: Changed the link of the full code, to link to another branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that — at least in the code you've shown here — your jit signature has four types, but the function you're decorating has five arguments:

```py
@jit(void(float_[:], float_, float_[:], numba.typed.Dict))
def state_dot(state, t, cmd, params, wind):
```

So obviously you need to fix that.  The easiest thing to try is to just remove the signature and let numba figure it out:

```py
@jit
def state_dot(state, t, cmd, params, wind):
```

Of course, even if you do this, numba still complains that it doesn't know how to type everything, and points to the line saying `mB = params["mB"]`.  It still does "loop lifting", which means that it's able to compile some things, but it won't be as fast as possible.

So the second thing to note is that while numba says it supports `dict`s, but then throws in a lot of caveats.  Basically, using a dict still is not a good idea.  I also don't see any good reason for you to use a dict.  Why not just make `mB` a member of your class, as in `self.mB = mB`?  I know you'll have more complicated things in your full `Quadcopter` class, but you can have lots of members.

Now, the third thing to note is that numba has gotten much better since I wrote [that gist you pointed out elsewhere](https://gist.github.com/moble/3aa44230256b66956587#gistcomment-2989530), and can now handle classes, so you might want to look into [`numba.jitclass`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html).  Generally, when you pass a jitclass object to a function you're trying to jit, numba will know how to handle it.

But perhaps more important than all of these is that your `update` method calls `odeint` for every single step.  I would guess that this is the slowest part of your code.  That function is meant to be called once, so that it can solve your whole problem from start to finish, and therefore it has lots of (relatively slow) overhead related to understanding the arguments you've passed, allocating memory, initializing things, etc.  A better way to do it is to construct a [`scipy.integrate.ode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.ode.html) object to keep everything set up between steps — and keep it around so that you can use the same one between steps.  The newer interfaces [`solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) and [`RK45`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html#scipy.integrate.RK45) (and similar) are roughly equivalent to `odeint` and `ode`, respectively, except that `ode` has my preferred solver `dop853`.  If you only need one of the `OdeSolver` subclasses, you might prefer those interfaces.  Also note that if you actually change anything in your state *between* steps, you may need to call `set_initial_value` again, or things might go wrong without you noticing.

More generally, if you're worried about speed, the best thing you can do is to profile your code.  The first step here is to just use [`%prun`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-prun) in ipython.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mike! Yeah, I liked the idea of having a dictionary for my parameters, but I knew that at some point I would have to change that. Either put them in a vector or each param becomes a member of `Quadcopter`. I'll try that, and I'll try setting up the `jitclass` for the wind object and see what improvements I get.

I'll also try `scipy.integrate.ode`. I didn't realize that what you explained was happening. It makes sense to use .ode in my case. Thankfully, I do not make changes to my state between steps. I'll report on my progress soon!

Comment: So I was able to implement numba in the example code I presented, but not in my actual script. They are supposed to be the same (same types, but not the same amount of members). I turned towards `scipy.integrate.ode`, and that works like a charm, my simulation runs more than twice as fast!